# Is it possible to check at runtime whether or not a TYPE_USE annotation is present on an interface within a implements declaration?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Consider the following:

```
class A implements @X B, C, @X D {}
```

Is it possible to retrieve at runtime whether or not the implements declaration contains @X on each of the implementing interfaces?

So in the above example, for B the answer is yes, for C no and for D yes.

If it is, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with [`Class#getAnnotatedInterfaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotatedInterfaces()).

> Returns an array of [`AnnotatedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedType.html) objects that represent the use of types to specify superinterfaces of the entity represented by this `Class` object. (The *use* of type `Foo` to specify a superinterface in '... implements Foo' is distinct from the *declaration* of type `Foo`.)
>
> *[...]*

For example:

```java
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedType;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE_USE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (AnnotatedType type : A.class.getAnnotatedInterfaces()) {
      System.out.println(type.getType());
      for (Annotation annotation : type.getAnnotations()) {
        System.out.println("\t" + annotation);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  @Target(TYPE_USE)
  @interface X {
    String value();
  }

  interface B {}
  interface C {}
  interface D {}

  static class A implements @X("Hello, ") B, C, @X("World!") D {}
}
```

Output:

```
interface com.example.Main$B
    @com.example.Main$X("Hello, ")

interface com.example.Main$C

interface com.example.Main$D
    @com.example.Main$X("World!")
```

Other similar methods include:

- [`Class#getAnnotatedSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotatedSuperclass())
- [`Method#getAnnotatedReturnType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getAnnotatedReturnType())
- [`Parameter#getAnnotatedType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getAnnotatedType())

Note that `AnnotatedType` has subtypes such as [`AnnotatedParameterizedType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedParameterizedType.html). That latter interface let's one get any annotations present on type arguments:

- [`AnnotatedParameterizedType#getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedParameterizedType.html#getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments())

To know whether or not an `AnnotatedType` is an instance of a subtype requires an `instanceof` test (unless you already know for sure).